# Google DMCA approved but link not removed

Tags: google-search, dmca

I had filed a DMCA against a website that had stolen my image. My review status shows approved but even after 2 weeks, the links were not removed from google search. While searching the image, it shows that In response to a complaint that we received under the US Digital Millennium Copyright Act, we have removed 1 result(s) from this page, but I still see the designated URL at the top of search results.

Comment: Did you fill from the DMCA or google website? Maybe, you should submit on
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/legal-removal-request?complaint_type=dmca&pid=3&visit_id=637178638311995009-2984423037&hl=en&rd=1&pli=1

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do, if there is a cancellation option, do not cancel it.  Let the request go un-interrupted through the removal process.

There is no timeframe available as to how long it takes to process a request.

Comment: The request has been processed and approved but the links have not been removed.

Comment: bro it takes time, maybe your competitor change its permalink! The Same thing is with my [manga website](https://www.mangastream.cc/). My competitors uses my own translated manga and when i am going to submit DMCA take down notices. it takes almost 20 days for the removals of that submitted url.